# Can't access to static variable android

Tags: java, android, json, static, android-sqlite

Overview; i need to create a json from a List to store in a sqlLite database. When i try to create the json Eclipse gets me an error that the variable List must be static. If this variable changed to static my application shows incorrect results and it's not a good thing. This is the class in which i create the json

```
public class Soluzione {
    public String durata;
    public List<Corsa> corse;

    public Soluzione() {
        corse = new ArrayList<Corsa>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        for (Corsa corsa : corse) {
            if (str.length() > 0)
                str.append('\n');
            str.append(corsa.toString());
        }

        return str.toString();
    }
    public static JSONObject CreateJSon(List<Corsa> corse)
    {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {

            Corsa prima = Soluzione.corse.get(0);
            Corsa ultima = Soluzione.corse.get(corse.size()-1);

            jObj.put("oraPartenza", prima.oraPartenza);
            jObj.put("oraArrivo", ultima.oraArrivo);
            jObj.put("partenza", prima.partenza);
            jObj.put("arrivo", ultima.arrivo);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would help if you just removed the `static` and actually read what `static` does and means: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I know what it means but it's about one week i can't find a solution! so i asked here.

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous between your field corse and the parameter of your method Create JSON.

Do not make method static and remove parameter

```
public JSONObject CreateJSon()
    {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {

            Corsa prima = Soluzione.corse.get(0);
            Corsa ultima = Soluzione.corse.get(corse.size()-1);

            jObj.put("oraPartenza", prima.oraPartenza);
            jObj.put("oraArrivo", ultima.oraArrivo);
            jObj.put("partenza", prima.partenza);
            jObj.put("arrivo", ultima.arrivo);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return jObj;
    }
```

EDIT :

so if you want to keep CreateJSon static, rename the parameter name to avoid ambiguity then :

```
Soluzione soluzione = new Soluzione();
Soluzione.CreateJSon (soluzione.corse);
```

OR you want to remove static attribute and you can remove parameter and you do :

```
Soluzione soluzione = new Soluzione();
soluzione.CreateJSon ();
```

Comment: mmmh....okok, but from the sqLite? And, i can't make corse static because change my result in the listview.

Comment: So don't make it static. Why your method needs to be static? I edited my answer to fit in your case.

Comment: because the database ask me to make it static. Follow me, if i make static corse, my result in the listview will be all the same. I will be a listview with 10 same rows. And this is not what i want.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the error? What methods has an error, it is not very clear...

Comment: initialValues.put("CORSA_DATA", Soluzione.CreateJSon(Soluzione.corse).toString());  requires that corse, in the Soluzione class, is static ok? But i can't make static corse. If corse is static i will have a wrong listview. If it is not static the results are ok. But i need to store the whole listview result in a database sqlite.. So i thought that the json could be the way..have you got anothe method?

Comment: ok, wait seems go now. I used an instance and it works. The only problem is that it stores only the last item of the list. I suppose that it's because of i need to create a for statement when i call the saveCorsa. Actually is something like   

corsaData.partenza = partenza.toString();
   corsaData.arrivo = arrivo.toString();
  SqlHelper.SaveCorsa(this, corsaData, corsaData.id);

I need a cycle right?

Comment: It is a different question, you should probably post a new question.